# How to correctly get size of content inflated and added to ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout

I cannot manage how to get inflated page element size.
Here is my code

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_flipper);
    GridIconsPageContent.MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new GridIconsPageContent.MyPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    ...
    --called new thread for populate data--
    ...
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent);
    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_banner, null);
    pagerAdapter.addPage(page);
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    page.getWidth()//retutns 0
```

page_banner layout is something kind of:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bannersPage"
            android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:orientation = "vertical">
</FrameLayout>
```

ViewPager layout is

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/home_flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background = "@android:color/white"/>
```

I cannot understand why `page.getWidth()` returns 0.
When I m getting sizes of ViewPager it returns correct values.
I'm new to Android platform, I think I miss something, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Can you please help me?

Regards,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = page.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
{
    public boolean onPreDraw()
    {
        int width = page.getMeasuredWidth();

        return true;
    }
});
```